# Pre-image of a subset that contains an element with no association.

Tags: functions

I got into an argument with my professor today in my beginner foundations in computer science course. We are using the textbook *Discrete Structures, Logic, and Computability*. At the bottom of the third page in Chapter 2, the book states:

$f^{-1}(\{1,3\})\ = \{a,b\}$

Given that $$f : \{a,b,c\} \rightarrow \{1,2,3\}$$ and $$f(a) = 1, f(b) = 1, f(c) = 2$$

She insisted that $f^{-1}(\{1,3\})$ is undefined, whereas I agree with the book. My thought process is that the pre-image finds the union of the sets in the domain that are associated with each element in the codomain. Who is correct?

Comment: Your thinking is right, but the words you use aren't quite right: the pre-image of a set $A$ comprises  the elements in the domain that are mapped to some element of $A$. See my answer for the formal expression of this.

Answer (score 1):

Your professor is wrong: if $f$ is a function $X \to Y$, and $A$ is any subset of $Y$, then $f^{-1}(A)$ is standard notation for the set $\{x \in X : \exists a \in A \cdot f(x) = a\}$. There is no requirement that $A$ is contained in the image of $f$.